Problem in deriving Killing equation
I am studying derivation of Killing equation by Wald (also reading some other literature) but having some problem in understanding the math.
Let $\chi ^a$ is killing vector on the horizon
$$\chi _{[a} \nabla_{b} \chi_{c]}=0$$
We will get 6 terms on the left hand side on expanding the above bracket (which I understand) and then by applying killing equation $\nabla_{a}  \chi_{b}+\nabla_{b} \chi_{a}=0$ we will get
$$\chi_{c} \nabla_{a} \chi_{b}=\chi_{b} \nabla_{a} \chi_{c}-\chi_{a} \nabla_{b} \chi_{c}$$
I understand this entire working. Now, How do we get the following equation?
$$\chi_{c} \nabla_{a} \chi_{b}=-2 \chi_{[a} \nabla_{b]}\chi_{c}.$$
Second question: I came across another equation while deriving it
$$\chi_{c}(\nabla^a \chi^b)(\chi_{a} \chi_{b})=-(\nabla^a \chi^b)(\chi_{a}\nabla_{b} \chi_{c})-(\nabla^b \chi^a)(\chi^b \nabla_{a} \chi_{c})$$
How do we get the following from the above equation?
$$=-2(\chi_{a} \nabla^a \chi^b)(\nabla_{b} \chi_{c})$$
Another question: If $\chi^{a} \chi_{a}=0$ (which is indeed on the horizon) does it mean $\chi_{a}\nabla^{b} \chi^{a}=0$ as well?
Should I ask this question in mathematics stack exchange ??

Question one: this is just notation for the antisymmetric part of a tensor
\begin{align}
\chi_{[a}\nabla_{b]}\chi_c\equiv\frac{1}{2}(\chi_{a}\nabla_{b}\chi_c-\chi_{b}\nabla_{a}\chi_c)
\end{align}
See definition in Wald equation (2.4.4)
Then
\begin{align}
-2\chi_{[a}\nabla_{b]}\chi_c
&\equiv-2\frac{1}{2}(\chi_{a}\nabla_{b}\chi_c-\chi_{b}\nabla_{a}\chi_c)\\
&=-\chi_{a}\nabla_{b}\chi_c+\chi_{b}\nabla_{a}\chi_c\\
&=\chi_{b}\nabla_{a}\chi_c-\chi_{a}\nabla_{b}\chi_c
\end{align}

Thank you for this explanation. Can you also answer my second question ?
